# how i can Toggle this ul by jquery

Tags: jquery

please any one can slideToggle this ul
i use the jquery

```
<ul id="flags_16">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="nb">
            <img src="en.png" class="imgvatb">langs</a>

        <ul style="display: none;">
        <li>
            <a href="en" class="nb">
                <img src="en.png" class="imgvatb"> english</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

</li>
```

Comment: Is there only one nested ul? Otherwise, give it an id. I assume when you say 'this ul' you mean the one styled with `display: none`

Comment: its styeld by 


<ul style="display: none;">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a link in your page, for example with the id 'list_toggle', then something like this should work:

```
$("#list_toggle").click(function () {
    $("#flags_16").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

More examples: http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/slideToggle

Comment: Or `$("#flags_16 li ul")` if that's the relevant one.